# How do I fix this jittery IK rig (No dependency cycles detected)

Tags: rigging, error, inverse-kinematics

I am trying to make a mechanical arm for a humanoid, but the elbow joint needs to be double jointed so it can flex correctly.

I have figured out how to make the joint flex evenly on both ends, however; despite having rid of any dependency cycles (I checked the console after saving and tabbing in and out of edit mode), I am still having strange jittering issues with my rig.

I suspect this has something to do with the IK Limits I have set up for the bones

[image: jitter]

**Blender Version:** 2.93

**IK Solver:** iTaSC

**IK Limits are Enabled for certain bones**

[image]

Comment: Here's how you upload a file: Grab the URL of the question.
Go to https://blend-exchange.com/.
Select the blend file.
Add the url of the question.
Grab the url that results.
Go back to the question and edit it.
Add the new url to the bottom of the post.

Comment: IK Chains work best if the initial configuration has a slight bend to help the IK solver figure out which way the chain should bend.  If that's not possible, then a pole target is a good choice.

Comment: @MartyFouts Thanks! Just uploaded the .blend

Comment: @MartyFouts I tried using a pole target but it did nothing - any other suggestions?

Comment: It's jumpy because your IK angle limits mean that it frequently cannot solve the IK.  This means that it is constantly jumping between best matches rather than interpolating smoothly between actual solutions.  Disable the limits on upperarm, and consider limiting the position of the IK target instead of trying to do it with IK angle limits.  Recommended also: give it a bend; don't use ITASC.

Comment: @Nathan there's something else wrong.  I've removed all of the constraints (I could find) and it's still jumpy.  I can create another rig in the same file where IK works fine, so I have no idea what's broken.

Comment: @MartyFouts Not constraints, the IK angle limits in properties/bone/IK.  (Maybe that's what you meant?)  I mentioned the upperarm limits, but the lowerarm_ik limits should really be removed as well and replaced with a bend, and the solver should be the standard one, as the ITASC is bugged out (disconnecting the connected lower arm in certain circumstances.)  This is speaking just for the IK chain; the question didn't ask about the other bones and I didn't look (although I'm always worried about limit rotation and fractional copy rotation.)

Comment: @MartyFouts when you say "remove lowearm_ik limits and replace them with a bend," what do you mean by that? Also, I just changed it back to the standard animation solver, as it did end up fixing the issue most of the time (there were still jittering issues but after what you said about the rig, I think its from the limits)

Comment: @Nathan I meant that I removed all of the IK limits, plus all of the Bone Constraints.  I did not try switching to the standard solver though.

Comment: Hectoris919 that comment was by @Nathan not me.

Comment: @MartyFouts You'll get rid of most of the jitter by removing the angle limits.  You'll get rid of the rest by using the default IK solver and creating a bend for a preferred angle.  ITASC just isn't good, and I think it's maybe even accrued some extra bugs over the years that nobody ever looks at (because there just aren't very many people using it, because it's not very good, because not many people use it....)