Animation intermittently skipping frames along the motion path during render
When I render a person doing complex movements with the legs driven by IK, the renders come out with a few skipped motions on the legs that ruin the movement.  Most of the character is moving smoothly but the legs driven by IK will randomly skip a frame of motion.  So the leg would be rotating and moving along a motion path that shows well-spaced dots but randomly stop on a frame and then jump 2 frames to catch up.  This causes jittery motion in the final output.
If I replay the render in the viewport, it will jump frames for that leg in random places.  Even if I manually forward the frames, the leg will also jump frames.  If I go back and forward with arrow keys, it will not jump the frame and render correctly and smoothly.  If it was just in the viewport I could live with it, but it is jumping randomly in the animation render.  Maybe 2 or 3 frames out of 200 will skip the leg motion in random places.  If I render it again, it will randomly skip in a different place.
A brute-force workaround is to output PNG files and find the frame that skipped, then manually re-render that frame and copy it over the skipped frame.  But this is extremely time-consuming and a complex workflow compared to just outputting MP4 video files.
Another slightly better workaround is to render 50 frames at a time and make sure that section is good.  If it's jittery, redo those 50 frames.  Then take the video segments and stitch them together with Avidemux into a single MP4.
If someone can suggest a way to solve this problem, that would be great.

Does the problem persist in a stripped-down version of your file? Maybe the most helpful we can be is to see whether we can reproduce it, in a share on https://blend-exchange.com/ , in an effort to exclude the possibility of a bug in the application.

I uploaded a stripped-down armature here that still exhibits the problem between frames 100 and 128.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XwSIGRmYcHQlDaG0Mq0SOA0dVx5QLrJA/view?usp=drive_link
The jitter happens before that too but it's easier to spot between 100 and 128.  The bone named mixamorig1:Femur3_R has a motion path traced out and if you manually advance the frames with arrows, you'll see it pause along the motion path and catch up by skipping an interpolated frame on the motion path.  It renders with this flaw as well.

Another post said the jitter is from problematic IK calculations and to remove the bone IK angle constraints.  That didn't seem to help that much when I did it.
My workaround of rendering 20 to 50 frames at a time and repeating until it randomly stops works, but it's time consuming and labor intensive.  The problem is random and doesn't even show up in the graph editor.  I've cleaned the graph editor motion and angle changes as much as I can.
I'm not as used to the IK workflow, but it makes keeping the feet pegged in one place easier rather than floating and penetrating the floor.

Thanks for the link ... (a connection to the other post you mention might be helpful, too.) This begins to look like a bug, which would mean it needs reporting, and we would not be the right people to resolve this,  here on BSE. I'm voting to leave this open for the time-being, in the hope that there is some fix via  the UI, that others can suggest.. let's hope we can be helpful.

Thanks for your help.  Should I report this bug directly to Blender?
Regarding the other link talking about jittery IK, I think that was due to IK bone axis constraints.  That doesn't seem to fix the problem for me even if I remove the IK axis constraints.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/234510/how-do-i-fix-this-jittery-ik-rig-no-dependency-cycles-detected

If none of us comes up with anything, yes, the report can be made via Header > Help. Then I think this post would be closed as 'off-topic', because we can't help. But let's give it a chance? I can't think of a fix myself, but it's not my area.

tbh i cannot see any skipping (but the motion path was outdated, so i first recreated it) and i couldn't see any problems....but...your example file couldn't be rendered so maybe that's "my" problem? can u provide a file which we can render (maybe just the leg which jumps) so that we can reproduce it? Or did i miss something? https://github.com/luckychris/blender_gifs/blob/main/manually%20frame%20by%20frame.gif
